# How to show that the union of two sets is a set defined by a function.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have found a hypothesis through experimental means that I would like to prove or disprove. My hypothesis is that the union of sets A and B is set C. Originally I thought this would have been an easy problem, but I'm having trouble writing logical statements to show that the union of two sets is the third.

```
Set A = (2^(2q+2)(6i-5)-1) / 3 where i and q are both positive integers
Set B = (2^(2q+1)(6i-1)-1) / 3 where i and q are both positive integers

Set C = 8i - 3 where i is a positive integer
```

The approach I've been taking is to show that given any value in A or B that the next smallest value in the union of A and B is [8 + current value].

Defenition of nomanclature

```
Let A(x,y) = (2^(2x+2)(6y-5)-1) / 3
Let B(x,y) = (2^(2x+1)(6y-1)-1) / 3
Let C(z) = 8z - 3
```

What I've been working on

```
min( 
    A(a+1,b) - A(a,b), 
    A(a,b+1) - A(a,b), 
    B(c+1,d) - A(a,b) where B(c,d) < A(a,b) < B(c+1,d), 
    B(c,d+1) - A(a,b) where B(c,d) < A(a,b) < B(c,d+1), 
    A(e+1,f) - A(a,b) where A(e,f) < A(a,b) < A(e+1,f), 
    A(e,f+1) - A(a,b) where A(e,f) < A(a,b) < A(e,f+1) 
) = 8
```

How and which topics should I be looking into to help me solve/show that `A union B = C`

Experimental Means - Python Code

````
def R():
    '''
    In Tandem work with notes
    Proof that omega is defined by w_i = 8i - 3
    :return:
    '''

    test_size = 1000000
    print_count_size = 20

    # I use 1->size because i is ZZ^+ //Zero is not included
    set_c = [8*i - 3 for i in range(1, test_size)]

    max_val_in_set_c = set_c[-1]

    set_a = list()
    set_b = list()

    i = 1
    while True:
        q = 1
        while True:
            
            val_a = (2 ** (2 * q + 2) * (6*i - 5) - 1) / 3
            val_b = (2 ** (2 * q + 1) * (6*i - 1) - 1) / 3

            '''
            If both are greater than the max in set C 
            we can stop iterating q and restart at 1 with the next i value
            '''
            if val_a > max_val_in_set_c and val_b > max_val_in_set_c:
                break

            if val_a <= max_val_in_set_c:
                set_a.append(val_a)

            if val_b <= max_val_in_set_c:
                set_b.append(val_b)

            q += 1

        '''
        If q has not been iterated then all further values will not be in the set and we can stop
        '''
        if q == 1:
            break
        else:
            i += 1

    union_set = set_a + set_b

    # Check for duplicates
    count_union_set = len(union_set)
    unique_union_set = set(union_set)
    if not count_union_set == len(unique_union_set):
        raise Exception("Duplicates Found")

    # sort the union set so that it'll be in the same order as set C
    union_set.sort()

    if not all([x == y for (x, y) in zip(union_set, set_c)]):
        print("Union Set")
        print(union_set[:print_count_size])
        print("Set C")
        print(set_c[:print_count_size])
        print("Delta")
        [print(i, x, y) for (i, x, y) in zip(range(1, test_size), union_set, set_c) if x != y]
        raise Exception(f"Written Does Not Match Calculated")
    else:
        print(f"Set C is in union of set A and B tested to {test_size}")

```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conjecture is true!

First, let $A = \{a(n,m) = \frac13 (2^{2n+2}(6m - 5) - 1) \mid n, m \in \mathbb{N}^+\}$, $B = \{b(n,m) = \frac13 (2^{2n+1}(6m - 1) - 1) \mid n, m \in \mathbb{N}^+\}$, and $C = \{8k - 3 \mid k \in \mathbb{N}^+\}$.

Calculating modulo 3 gives $2^{2n+2}(6m-5) - 1 \equiv ((-1)^2)^{n+1} (0 + 1) - 1 = 1 - 1 = 0$, so the elements in $A$ are actually integers. As $n$ is positive, $2^{2n+2}$ is always divisible by 8. Calculating modulo 8 we get $\frac13 (2^{2n+2}(6m - 5) - 1) = 3(0 - 1) = -3$, so we can write $a(n,m)$ as $8k - 3$ for some integer $k$. Because $a(n,m)$ is positive, so is $k$. This proves $a(n,m) \in C$ for all $n, m$, so $A \subseteq C$. One can prove $B \subseteq C$ in exactly the same way.

Now prove $C \subseteq A \cup B$. Let $k \in \mathbb{N}^+$. Write $3k - 1 = 2^r u$, where $r$ is a nonnegative integer and $u$ is an odd positive integer. If $r$ is even, wrtie $r = 2s$. Choose $n = s + 1$ and $m = \frac{u+1}{6}$. Clearly, $n$ is a positive integer. $m$ is also positive, but it is not so clear that it is an integer. We know that $u$ is odd, so $u+1$ is divisible by 2. Moreover, considering $3k - 1 = 2^{2s} u = 4^s u$ modulo 3 gives $-1 \equiv 1^s u = u$, so $u+1$ is divisible by 3. In total, $u+1$ is divisible by 6, so $m$ is a positive integer. Now calculate
$$b(n,m) = \frac13(2^{2s+3}(6\frac{u+1}{6} - 1) - 1) = \frac13(8u2^{2s} - 1) = \frac13(24k - 9) = 8k - 3 = c(k)$$
This proves $c(k) \in B$. If $r$ is odd, you can show $c(k) \in A$ in a similar way. Write $r = 2s + 1$ and choose $n = s+1$ and $m = \frac{u+5}6$.